# Hibernate java getting a complete object

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to get the complete A object from database, this include the B object that contains the C and D.

I have A B C D classes

```
class A
private B object

Class B
private List<C> objects

Class C
private List<D> objects
```

This is what I do:

```
Session session = sf.openSession();
            String consulta = "select a from A a;
            Query q = session.createQuery(consulta);
            List<A> aaaa= q.list();
```

This is getting the A with B, but B is not containing the list of C.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN FETCH` in your query to get everything in one go:

```
Query q = "select b from B b join fetch b.c";
```

This addresses the [N+1 problem](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/how-identify-and-resilve-n1) that you would have if you initialized everything lazily.